# Can this table be updated without mysql stored procedure?

Tags: mysql

I have three tables user, user_status, owner.

### user_status

```
id,userId,ownerId
1, 1001, 0
2, 1002, 0
3, 1003, 0
```

### user

```
userId, ownerId
1001, 2001, ....
1002, 2002, ....
1003, 2003, ....
```

### owner

```
ownerId, name ...
0, ...
2001, ...
2002, ...
```

I would want to update the user_status table with ownerIds corresponding to the actual userIds. So that after update user_status table looks like below.

### user_status

```
1, 1001, 2001
2, 1002, 2002
3, 1003, 2003
```

Is it possible to do it without a stored procedure?

Comment: Yes: `update user_status s set ownerId = (select ownerId from user u where s.userId = u.userId)`

Answer (score 0):

```
update user_status set ownerId = (select ownerId from user where user.userId = user_status.userId)
```

Comment: Please also explain the code to be a bit more educative.